# When I call a function in child class it is instead calling the parent class function

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, overriding

I am working on a project where I have an array of children classes.
I want to call an overridden child function from the array, but instead it calls the parent function.

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent {
public:
    Parent(){}
    void print() {
        std::cout << "I'm the parent!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ChildOne : public Parent {
public:
    ChildOne(){}
    void print() {
        std::cout << "I'm childOne!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ChildTwo : public Parent {
public:
    ChildTwo() {}
    void print() {
        std::cout << "I'm childTwo!" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Parent arr[] = {ChildOne(), ChildTwo()};
    int n = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i].print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is

```
I'm the parent!
I'm the parent!
```

Where the output I want is

```
I'm childOne!
I'm childTwo!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the member function of `Parent` needs to be `virtual`.

```
class Parent
{
   public:
       Parent(){}
       virtual void print() {std::cout << "I'm the parent!" << std::endl;};
};
```

Then the children need to override it.   In C++11 and later, it is advisable to use `override`

```
class ChildOne : public Parent
{
   public:
      ChildOne(){}
      void print() override {std::cout << "I'm childOne!" << std::endl;};
};
```

The second thing to address is that your code in `main()`

> ```
> Parent arr[] = {ChildOne(), ChildTwo()};
> ```

initialises two `Parent` objects by slicing i.e.  `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are both of type `Parent`, not of `ChildOne` or `ChildTwo` respectively.

To address that is it necessary that `arr` be an array of pointers, and initialised accordingly.

```
 Parent *arr[] = {new ChildOne(), new ChildTwo()};
```

which can be followed up with

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    arr[i]->print();
}

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)    // to avoid a memory leak
{
    delete arr[i];
}
//  don't use elements of `arr` here
```

A better way (C++11 and later) is to write `main()` is to use `std::unique_ptr` from the standard header `<memory>`)

```
std::unique_ptr<Parent> arr[] = {new ChildOne(), new ChildTwo()};
```

which allows doing away with the loop to release the elements of `arr`.   In C++14 and later, the objects in `arr` can be created using `std::make_unique()`.

Answer (score 4):

You're implicitly casting all your instances to type `Parent` when you store them in that typed array. Since you are using static dispatch, you're always going to call the method on the base type you've (implicitly) downcasted to.

Comment: Search term for more information [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Answer (score 2):

Your code suffers from two problems:

1. you are not actually overriding `print()` at all, because it is not `virtual`.  So you are merely *overloading* it in each child class, *hiding* the parent's method.
2. you are [slicing your objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) when storing them into your array.  So, it doesn't matter if `print()` is virtual, since there are no child objects in the array, only parent objects.  Polymorphism works correctly only when using pointers/references to base classes.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent {
public:
    Parent(){}
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "I'm the parent!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ChildOne : public Parent {
public:
    ChildOne(){}
    void print() override {
        std::cout << "I'm childOne!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ChildTwo : public Parent {
public:
    ChildTwo() {}
    void print() override {
        std::cout << "I'm childTwo!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    ChildOne c1;
    ChildTwo c2;
    Parent* arr[] = {&c1, &c2};

    int n = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i]->print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the parent function as `virtual`, and the child functions should utilize the `override` keyword.

```
class Parent {
public:
    Parent(){}
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "I'm the parent!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ChildOne : public Parent {
public:
    ChildOne(){}
    void print() override {
        std::cout << "I'm childOne!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ChildTwo : public Parent {
public:
    ChildTwo() {}
    void print() override {
        std::cout << "I'm childTwo!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: The OP's code suffers from "object slicing" when populating the array, so this is only part of the fix that is needed.  The array needs to be fixed, too.